# What do I do with the giant cubic rocks?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Does anyone know what ride Pokemon I need to break the big grey cubic boulders in Pokemon sun and moon.
And where can I get the ride Pokemon needed to break it

Answer (score 3):

Those rocks are the equivalent of the boulders in previous Pokémon games that you needed the Strength HM to move. In Sun & Moon, you need the Machamp ride pager to move them. It will be unlocked once you get to Poni Island and speak with Hapu's grandmother. See [this Serebii page](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/pokeride.shtml).